# Outlook Interop: how to get deleted items folder or trash folder for each of the accounts

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm trying to get all the **Deleted Items** or **Trash** folders for all the mail accounts in Outlook. I'm using Outlook Interop in C#, but I can only find the way to get the deleted items folder in the default mail account on MSDN: `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems)`.

Does anybody know if there is a way that I can get the deleted items folder in every email accounts in Outlook?

Comment: Are these exchange accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the `Namespace.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)` instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`.

Comment: That will only work if they are all on the same outlook profile. If they are on different profiles things will have to get creative.

Comment: The OP did not mention anything about multiple profiles, so I assume all the stores are in the same profile.

Comment: I just realised that my component needs to support Outlook 2007, which does not have the GetDefaultFolder method in the Store interface.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the "should work on Outlook 2007" requirement you added in your response to Dmitry's answer, I'd suggest the following approach:

1. Use a `PropertyAccessor` to acquire the PR_IPM_WASTEBASKET_ENTRYID ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x35E30102") of the store
2. Use `PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString` to convert it to an EntryID you can use in the COM/interop layer
3. Use `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` to access the deleted items folder folder, given it's EntryID and the EntryID of the store.